# Как узнать кликнутую букву?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть текст, который находится внутри div. При нажатии надо получить позицию буквы/слова, на которое произошел клик. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: позицию относительно чего ?

Comment: @ryzen, Относительно строки. Весь текст хранится в строке и мне надо при нажатии определить слово и обернуть его в span.

Comment: А финальная цель-то какая? Пишете текстовый редактор, или для чего нужно выделить слово? Если вот просто выделить, ответ Артема - самое то: Один раз всё обернуть в span, и больше не трогать innerHTML: При клике менять класс элемента (который покрасит в другой цвет, например)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, да, я пишу текстовый редактор. Мне нужно определять слово, на которое произошел клик, чтобы его:
1. Подсвечивать (показать активность)
2. При свайпе удалить
3. Показать его вариации и при необходимости удалить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/range-textrange-selection) упоминается об объекте `Range`

> Range – это объект, соответствующий фрагменту документа, который может включать узлы и участки текста из этого документа. Наиболее подробно объект Range описан в спецификации  [DOM Range](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html).

Вам необходимо использовать свойство startOffset

> Свойство startOffset (endOffset) вернёт смещение для верхней (нижней) граничной точки.

приведен код и ссылка где [можно посмотреть пример](https://plnkr.co/edit/1SPXvhAz573RZQdo?p=preview&preview):

```
var range = getRangeObject();
    if (range) {
        alert( range );
        alert( range.startContainer.nodeValue );
        alert( range.startOffset );
        alert( range.endOffset );
    } else {
        alert( 'Ничего не выделено' );
    }
```

}

UPD: для получения определенного символа необходимо использовать

```
range.startContainer.nodeValue.substring(range.startOffset, range.startOffset+1)
```

Comment: мы же можем использовать к примеру substring range.startContainer.nodeValue.substring(range.startOffset, range.startOffset+1)

Comment: Ах да, я ошибся, всё-таки работает

Comment: за замечание, спасибо, обновлю, что бы было более понятно

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - можно переработать текст так, чтобы каждая буква была внутри тега span с атрибутами data-word и data-letter - а также обработчиком события click.
То бишь, ввести подобную функцию:

```
const generateText = (text) => {
    return text.split(' ').map((word, indexWord)=>word.split('').map((letter, letterIndex)=>`<span data-word=${indexWord} data-letter=${letterIndex} onclick="clickHandler(event)">${letter}</span>`).join('')).join(' ');
}
```

В div нужно отправлять результат обработки вашего текста с помощью этой функции (через innerHTML, или средствами каких-либо других библиотек, если вы их используете). А вот возможный обработчик клика:

```
const clickHandler = (event) => {
    let wordIndex = event.target.getAttribute('data-word');
    let letterIndex = event.target.getAttribute('data-letter');
    console.log(`word: ${wordIndex}; letter: ${letterIndex}`);
}
```

UPD: это решение может оказаться низкопроизводительным

Comment: Только это будут позиции, считая от 0, разумеется

Comment: Разве это не будет слишком ресурсоемко? У меня будет 1500+ слов.

Comment: Вам ведь, вероятно, в любом случае потребуется визуально выделять буквы, на которые происходит клик. В этом случае все равно будет не обойтись без отдельных элементов под каждую букву.
Главная проблема в том, что мое решение все же не совсем верное. Я сейчас перепроверил - событие не погружается так, как я рассчитывал, следовательно, придется навешивать каждому span свой обработчик - пусть и с одной и той же функцией. Вот это уже может быть действительно ресурсоемко...

Comment: Есть еще одна идея, правда звучит она бредово: строго сверстать этот div с текстом - так, чтобы обработчик клика на див мог исходя из координат понять, над какой буквой пришелся клик

Comment: Ой, 1500 слов для JS ни о чем) Даже 10.000. Хотя зависит и от задачи конечно.

Comment: Если в каждом слове каждую букву заключать в span с обработчиком события и если считать, что в каждом слове в среднем по 7 букв (грубо говоря), то выходит порядка 11к элементов внутри одного контейнера - каждый при двух пользовательских аргументах и ивентхендлере. Помимо остального на странице, разумеется...

Comment: @АртемВагин, я изначально и планировал определять позицию буквы относительно начала, а потом получать слово и т.д.

Comment: Что ж, это тоже вариант. В принципе, если выставить в css определенные word-spacing, letter-spacing и line-height, то получится может. Да и в адаптивности с этими свойствами можно и не потерять сильно, думаю.

Comment: Решил использовать ваш метод, но возникла проблема. У меня есть перенос строки (\n), а его ваш код не читает. Строка переносится, но для неё не создается нового span. `return text.split(' ').map((word, indexWord)=>\`<span data-word=${indexWord} onclick="clickHandler(event)">${word}</span>\`).join(' ');` Как такое исправить? P.s.: в .map вообще не разбираюсь.

Comment: @SireIMPACTUS `.split(/\s/)` - это означает "Любой пробельный символ", куда входит и перенос строки. Но стоп... какой span, если есть \n ? Если используете contentEditable блок, посмотрите его код на странице. На самом деле у него нет переносов строки: Каждая строчка, это отдельный div.

Comment: Да. А если не используете contentEditable, но текст все равно подразумевает перенос строки, то используйте вместо "\n" тег br. Можете использовать регулярное выражение в split из предыдущего комментария вместо пробела, а после обработки заменить все вхождения '\n' в полученной строке `text.replace(/\\n/g, '<br>')`